# Asymptotic expansion of non analytical function

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, analyticity, smooth-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a real smooth (not necessarily analytical) function.
Suppose I tell you that $f(t)$ admits a full asymptotic, at $t\rightarrow0$ expansion up to all orders of $t$

$$f(t)\sim\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{i_n}t^{c_{i_n}}\quad\quad t\rightarrow 0$$

where $c_{i_n}$ is a increasing sequence of naturals.

I saw this on an article and have no clue what it means. Specifically what does $\sim$ is in this case?

- Can it mean $f(t)-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{i_n}t^{c_{i_n}}= \mathcal{o}(g)$ where $g$ is a non analytical smooth functions that is strictly bounded by any polynomial? Like $g(x)=1-e^{1/x}$?

Any clarification would be deeply appreciated.
PS: There is really nothing else in the article that explains this better so I am hoping its some common knowledge that I'm not aware of.

Comment: $f(t)\sim\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_n t^n$ as $t\to 0$ means $f(t)-\sum\limits_{n=0}^Nc_n t^n \ll t^N$ for all $N$ as $t \to 0$. The $\sim$ reads `is asymptotic to'. Also, $f(t)\ll g(t)$ as $t \to 0$ means $\lim_{t \to0}\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}=0$

Comment: It is a bad notation which means what Sal said (don't use it!)

Comment: For the general defintion, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion#Formal_definition).  In your case $L=0$, $a_n=c_{i_n}$ and $\varphi_n(x)=x^{c_{i_n}}$. I disagree with reuns, everyone in the field of asymptotic expansions uses this notation and we have absolutely no issue with it. You just have to understand what it means.

Comment: @Gary Really? $\sim$ means $f(x)/g(x)\to 1$ not "let's compare the function with a formal series that doesn't converge". You should really think again about notations, like don't use the same symbols for two different things on one line and the next one.

Comment: Suppose f is integrable. Define $g(x)=\int_0^{\infty}f(t)dt$. What's $g(x)\sim$ to?

Comment: @JoséDuartedeAzevedoeCunha $\int_0^\infty f(t) dt$ does not depend on $x$.